# How to convert a Row into a Column if it starts overflowing?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there any other way besides me manually checking if a `Row` overflows, convert it into a `Column`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`OverflowBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OverflowBar-class.html) which comes out of the box with Flutter SDK.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return OverflowBar(
    children: [
      Container(height: 100, width: 200, color: Colors.blue),
      Container(height: 100, width: 200, color: Colors.orange),
      Container(height: 100, width: 200, color: Colors.white),
      Container(height: 100, width: 200, color: Colors.black),
    ],
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) widget which works a little bit like a Grid. Not entirely sure if it will solve your question of converting a row to a column, but in cases where the items fill in a row, the widget will start placing them in a new row.

Secondly, you may also use the [Flex](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flex-class.html) widget which takes a parameter of either horizontal or vertical orientation (row/column) and adjust the parameter based on the screen size.

Comment: First, `Wrap` can't fulfil my needs because it will stay in horizontal direction (unless I change it explicitly). Second `Flex` is also not going to do much good because the child may overflow in horizontal axis.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GridView` is the better choice for your case.
Take a look at this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLOtZDTm4H8) provided by Flutter Team.

Comment: Let's say I only have to show 4 elements either horizontally (first choice) or vertically (if horizontal fails), how `GridView` will give me the desired UI. I think you overlooked the question.

Comment: @iDecode sorry for my misunderstanding. You may check it manually and then use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` to determine using `Row` or `Column`. Let's say each element need 100px, so if `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` < 400 use `Row`, otherwise use `Column`. But it only works for static element.

Comment: So instead of doing that check, don't you think a simple `OverflowBar` is much better?

Comment: yeah you are right, never tried it before until now. Thanks! Have a great day!